# I don't understand calling a Method in C#

Tags: c#

I'm struggling with understanding this assignment, It wants me to call a method to average out a grade and I can wrap my mind around how. The book I'm using doesn't do a great job at explaining what a method is, or how to do it well.

I should also clarify, I'm not a student.

```
using System;

namespace PracticeChapter4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const float MATH_GRADE          = 80.0f;
            const float BIOLOGY_GRADE       = 80.0f;
            const float PROGRAMMING_GRADE   = 92.0f;
            const string STUDENT_NAME       = "G. Treele";
            float average = CalculateAverage(MATH_GRADE, BIOLOGY_GRADE, PROGRAMMING_GRADE); // Call CalculationAverage() to calculate the average grade.//
            ShowAverage(STUDENT_NAME, average); // Call ShowAverage() to display the student name and overall average.//
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void average()
        {   
            const float TOTAL                   = 3;
            Console.WriteLine(average/TOTAL);
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_methods.asp

Comment: See here for what a method is: [Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods). For something simpler, see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_methods.asp)

Comment: Your local variable `float average` is hiding the method `Program.average()`. You haven't defined either `CalculateAverage(params float[])` or `ShowAverage(string, float)`

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's [Methods in (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods) says:

> A method is a code block that contains a series of statements. A program causes the statements to be executed by calling the method and specifying any required method arguments.

The guide has also plenty of useful examples, like the one below:

```
public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      // Call with an int variable.
      int num = 4;
      int productA = Square(num);

      // Call with an integer literal.
      int productB = Square(12);

      // Call with an expression that evaluates to int.
      int productC = Square(productA * 3);
   }

   static int Square(int i)
   {
      // Store input argument in a local variable.
      int input = i;
      return input * input;
   }
}
```